# Change appconfig on runtime

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to update the appconfig file on run time with the following code. I do not get an error but it does not update my config file.

```
System.Configuration.Configuration config =
    ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
string oldValue = config.AppSettings.Settings["Username"].Value;
config.AppSettings.Settings["Username"].Value = "NewValue";
config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");
```

Answer (score 3):

Adding the `config.AppSettings.SectionInformation.ForceSave = true;` will do the trick. You should then look in `YourProject.vshost.exe.config` when debugging as Justin said. The modifications are saved there.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you have write access to the app.config file the following should work.

```
// To Save
System.Configuration.Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
config.AppSettings.Settings["Username"].Value = "NewValue";
config.AppSettings.SectionInformation.ForceSave = true;
config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);

// To Refresh
ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");
System.Configuration.Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't update a configuration. You have to remove it and then add it again. This has worked for me, including while debugging through Visual Studio:

```
config.AppSettings.Settings.Remove("Username");
config.AppSettings.Settings.Add("Username", "NewValue");
config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
```

Answer (score 0):

When I need to update my configuration, I always have to use:

```
config.AppSettings.SectionInformation.ForceSave = true;
//Save config
//Refresh Config section
```

Otherwise it doesn't update the configuration file for me.

Also, are you running this in Visual Studio?  If you are debugging from Visual Studio, it creates copies int he bin folder so in your actual project, you won't see any changes to the configuration unless you looked at the configuration file in the bin\debug folder.