# want to create ".cs" file which can include my app.config members

Tags: c#

I did app.config .now I want to make new file ".cs" where I want to do access the credential that I used in "app.config" ..I used in existing ".cs" ...but want to make new ".CS" file ...so it will be easy to handle an change that I want to do ..plz help

```
namespace CommoditiesControl.RatePuller
{
    public class DBConnect
    {
        private MySqlConnection connection;
        private string server;
        private int port;
        private string database;
        private string uid;
        private string password;

        //Constructor
        public DBConnect()
        {
            Initialize();
        }

        //Initialize values
        private void Initialize()
        {

            string DBserver = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["server"];
            int DBport = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["port"]);
            string DBdatabase = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["eagri"];
            string uid = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["test"];
            string password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[""];
        }
        string connectionString;
        connectionString = "SERVER=" + server + ";" +
                            "DATABASE=" + database + ";" +
                            "User Id=" + uid + ";" +
                            "PASSWORD=" + password + ";" +
                            "PORT=" + port + ";" +
                            "Connect Timeout=240";
        // string connectionString = "server=localhost;User Id=test;database=eagri;port=13306";
        connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
    }

    //open connection to database
    private bool OpenConnection()
    {
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            return true;
        }
        catch (MySqlException ex)
        {
            //The two most common error numbers when connecting are as follows:
            //0: Cannot connect to server, access denied.
            //1045: Invalid user name and/or password.
            switch (ex.Number)
            {
                case 0:
                    Console.WriteLine("Cannot connect to server.  Access Denied");
                    break;

                case 1045:
                    Console.WriteLine("Invalid username/password, please try again");
                    break;

                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Unable to connect to mysql server, unknown error {0}", ex.ToString());
                    break;
            }
            return false;
        }

    }

    //Close connection
    public bool CloseConnection()
    {
        try
        {
            connection.Close();
            return true;
        }
        catch (MySqlException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            return false;
        }
    }

    //Insert statement
    public void Insert(string query)
    {
        //open connection
        if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
        {
            //create command and assign the query and connection from the constructor
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);

            //Execute command
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            //close connection
            this.CloseConnection();
        }
    }

    //Update statement
    public void Update(string query)
    {
        //Open connection
        if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
        {
            //create mysql command
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
            //Assign the query using CommandText
            cmd.CommandText = query;
            //Assign the connection using Connection
            cmd.Connection = connection;

            //Execute query
            int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            Console.WriteLine("DB update result: {0} updated", i);

            //close connection
            this.CloseConnection();
        }
    }

    //Delete statement
    public void Delete(string query)
    {
        if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
        {
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            this.CloseConnection();
        }
    }

    //Select statement
    public MySqlDataReader Select(string query)
    {
        MySqlDataReader dataReader = null;

        //Open connection
        if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
        {
            //Create Command
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
            //Create a data reader and Execute the command
            dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        }

        return dataReader;
    }

    //Count statement
    public int Count(string query)
    {
        int Count = -1;

        //Open Connection
        if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
        {
            //Create Mysql Command
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);

            //ExecuteScalar will return one value
            Count = int.Parse(cmd.ExecuteScalar() + "");

            //close Connection
            this.CloseConnection();
        }
        return Count;
    }

    //Backup
    public void Backup()
    {
    }

    //Restore
    public void Restore()
    {
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Your question is unclear to me

Comment: I made cofig .app ..where I used  string DBserver = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["server"];
& so on ...but now I have to make new file program ".cs" file from where I can do any change in string DBserver = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["server"];
from that

Comment: you're setting the values in local variables. set them in instance variables `this.server = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["server"]` then you can create new instance of `DBConnect` and use it if you have exposed it as a public property

Comment: you don't think that I want to make new CLass ? and will I have to use static constant ???

Answer (score 0):

```
connection = DBServer;
port = DBport;
database = DBdatabase;
etc...
```

But remember that your application on loads the Configigurationfile once at application load time, so you need to force update it to get new values if you change it runtime
[Change appconfig on runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15137464/change-appconfig-on-runtime)

Comment: but with out defining any class how can I preside & well as u said how can I be connect with the previous program where port is called ???

Comment: I woul dnot connect to the previeous database session, I wcreate a new session, is there a reason you need to connect to the same session? Also I dont think you can store complex objects like a Database connection in app.config, only for example a connectionstring

Comment: in my app.config what I did <add key="database" value="eagri"/>...like this ..& now I wnt to make new .cs so that ..it will help me to resolve the problem

Comment: Make Connection a public property and then either make a DBConnect instance in the new class file, or use dependency injection like http://www.ninject.org/download.html then you can access the connection property from the other class